# adb downgrade install fails even with -d

Tags: applications, adb

I'm attempting to install a pretty old version of Chrome (44.0.2403.133) on a Nexus 5X (Android 6).  It already has Chrome on it so I ran

```
adb install -r -d path/to/chrome.apk
```

However, even with `-d`, it still failed with

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE]
```

Examining the logcat output, this line stands out to me:

```
W PackageManager: Package com.android.chrome new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does.
```

Comment: There's an explanation for this error on [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34791678/2821954).